# SwiftUI - change Model from nested subviews

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, viewmodel, lazyvstack

I have a LazyVStack presenting Cells.
My main View which has the LazyVStack has a viewModel.

```
@StateObject private var model = ViewModel()
```

The Stack presents a list of CustomViews.

```
LazyVStack {
    ForEach(model.items) { item in
       CustomView(item: item)
    }
}
```

Each custom view consists from two other subviews, CustomView1 and CustomView2.
CustomView2 has a button, where onTap I want to flip the cell.

However at that point my Custom views have a new copy of these items (struct).
What is the best approach to point back to the model to achieve:

```
.onTapGesture {
   model.flipItem(item)
}
```

- Somehow multiple @Binding variables is an option ?
- Making the ViewModel shared singleton for easy access ?
- Better option ?

Comment: Look at `EnvironmentObject` that is how you share a `StateObject` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 1):

I would add a property inside your `Item` struct that stores if the card is flipped or not:

```
struct Item {
    var ifFlipped = false
    ...
}
model.items = [Item(), Item()]
```

Then loop over `model.items.indices`, so that you can get the `Binding`:

```
LazyVStack {
    ForEach(model.items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
       CustomView(item: $model.items[index]) /// this will be a Binding<Item>
    }
}
```

And your `CustomView`/`CustomView1` will need to look something like this.

```
struct CustomView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomView1(item: $item) /// pass Binding down
    }
}

struct CustomView1: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi")
            .onTapGesture {
                item.isFlipped.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion. What if the button is further down the line ? Would I have to ExtractViews only once ?

Comment: @PoolHallJunkie just keep passing the `Binding` down (see my edit). But what do you mean by "ExtractViews"?

Comment: I see a couple of problems with this solution. Can't pass the model as its a StateObject. But by passing the item itself it means that I have to remove any private properties from my viewModel and allow external functions to edit my items.

Comment: @PoolHallJunkie I think technically you can pass the model via `@ObservedObject` instead of `@Binding`, but why would you want that? And how come you need to remove private properties from your viewModel?

Comment: If my model items are private(set), I can't pass them as $model.items[index] because the model will not be mutable. I made it work but I am changing the model from the CustomView struct instead of inside the ModelView.

Comment: @PoolHallJunkie ah, I see.

Comment: `@Binding` will not work with a `private(set)` because it is a two-way connection. The only option is to somehow pass your `StateObject` You can use the singleton or `@EnvironmentObject`.